# Sencha Touch 2.4 and twetter api 1.1 as json in store

Tags: php, json, twitter, sencha-touch-2

I created a json store in sencha touch using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQaPt-gQVRI

the Json is looks like the following:

```
[
{
    "created_at": "Sat Apr 05 20:06:38 +0000 2014",
    "id": 34563456345646,
    "id_str": "5643563456456",
    "text": "My lovely boy: Adrian,  04.04.2014 only 2 hours old!!! http://t.co/1F8MhRa0eH",
    "source": "<a href=\"http: //twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 456456,
        "id_str": "4356456",
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "screen_name": "xxxxxxx",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": [

                ]
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 8,
        "friends_count": 18,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Fri Mar 09 00:08:22 +0000 2012",
        "favourites_count": 1,
        "utc_offset": 7200,
        "time_zone": "Berlin",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 11,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "282828",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/577489227/58nipt5bo41ae2tkq02g.jpeg",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/577489227/58nipt5bo41ae2tkq02g.jpeg",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1882584072/image_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1882584072/image_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "FC0243",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "D0F2DD",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "D3DFD1",
        "profile_text_color": "D7CAC3",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [

        ],
        "symbols": [

        ],
        "user_mentions": [

        ],
        "urls": [

        ],
        "media": [
            {
                "id": 452537815365333000,
                "id_str": "452537815365332992",
                "indices": [
                    55,
                    77
                ],
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bke8vtRIMAAB2QK.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bke8vtRIMAAB2QK.jpg",
                "url": "http://t.co/1F8MhRa0eH",
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/1F8MhRa0eH",
                "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/xxxxxx/status/452537817038848001/photo/1",
                "type": "photo",
                "sizes": {
                    "small": {
                        "w": 340,
                        "h": 255,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "w": 600,
                        "h": 450,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "thumb": {
                        "w": 150,
                        "h": 150,
                        "resize": "crop"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "w": 1024,
                        "h": 768,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [
            {
                "id": 452537815365333000,
                "id_str": "452537815365332992",
                "indices": [
                    55,
                    77
                ],
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bke8vtRIMAAB2QK.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bke8vtRIMAAB2QK.jpg",
                "url": "http://t.co/1F8MhRa0eH",
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/1F8MhRa0eH",
                "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/xxxxx/status/452537817038848001/photo/1",
                "type": "photo",
                "sizes": {
                    "small": {
                        "w": 340,
                        "h": 255,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "w": 600,
                        "h": 450,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    },
                    "thumb": {
                        "w": 150,
                        "h": 150,
                        "resize": "crop"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "w": 1024,
                        "h": 768,
                        "resize": "fit"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en"
}
```

}
]
but the json data is too complex and i canot get the media_url in entities, I made a mapping in model to reach other part but the mapping is not working in case of media_url!!

please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

YOu are not getting proper node. Get the proper node and do mapping.

Other work around is you create mapping for entities and can use convert function 
and get media url.

```
 {
 name : 'mediaUrl',
 type : 'string',
 convert : function(v, record) {
 var entities= record.get('entities');
 var meridaUrl= entities.media[0].media_url;
  return meridaUrl;
  }},
```

try this and let me know.

Comment: tnx for your help , unfortunately getting error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: record is not defined' in var entities= record.get('entities');, it looks like it id not defined !

Comment: you have to define one field in the model with name  entities and map that to the your entities in json object.. then it will work if you have any issue provide me code snippet of model i will modify and give to you,,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
entities.media[0].media_url
```